# Handling unexpected side effect in computed properties - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the following code, I'm trying to use the `getTranslation` object to map values present in `originalKeys` array and push the values in a new array `allKeys`.

But ESLint is giving me this error, `Unexpected side effect in "getkeys" computed property.`

I tried shifted the getkeys function to methods, but I think that it does not make sense to call a method everytime to get the translation done. 
How can I solve this issue?

```
<template>
    <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="key in getkeys" v-bind:key="key"> {{ key }}</option
    </select>
</template>

data(){
    return{
    selected: '',
    allKeys: [],
    originalKeys: [],  //e.g. ["ALPHA_MIKE]
    getTranslation: {} //e.g. {"ALPHA_MIKE": "ALPHA MIKE"}
    }
},
computed: {
    getkeys(){
        let tableHeaders = [];
        for( var i=0; i<this.originalKeys.length; i++){
            let translation = this.getTranslation[this.originalKeys[i]];
            tableHeaders.push(translation);
        }
        this.selected = tableHeaders[0]; //unexpected side effect here
        this.allKeys = tableHeaders; //unexpected side effect here.
        return this.allKeys;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not edit other data in `computed`, you should use `watch` instead

Comment: So do you mean that I should write the `getkeys` in `watch`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As my above comment, you should not edit other data in `computed` property, you should use `watch` instead

```
computed: {
    getkeys(){
        let tableHeaders = [];
        for( var i=0; i<this.originalKeys.length; i++){
            let translation = this.getTranslation[this.originalKeys[i]];
            tableHeaders.push(translation);
        }
        return tableHeaders;
    }
},
watch: {
  getkeys: {
    deep: true,
    handler: function (newVal) {
      this.selected = newVal[0]
      this.allKeys = newVal
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why is this a good idea? I get it that it narrows down the source of error but it's insanely infuriating since none of these quirks have any mentions in the docs.

Answer (score 13):

As other answers mentioned this is because you are mutating the original data in a computed property. You should use a method to do this part of the job.

```
methods:{
    changes(tableHeaders){
        this.selected = tableHeaders[0];
        this.allKeys = tableHeaders;
    }
},
computed:{
    getkeys(){
        // Your code...
        this.changes(tableHeaders);
    }
},
data: function(){
    return{
        // Your data...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

ESLint is showing this error because you are mutating the original data in computed property. It is recommended that you should return new references or data from computed property.Follow this link for detailed explanation.
https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.md

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to move `allKeys` array to computed and get rid of unnecessary `tableHeaders` and `getKeys`:

```
<template>
    <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="key in allKeys" v-bind:key="key"> {{ key }}</option
    </select>
</template>

data(){
    return{
    selected: '',
    originalKeys: [],  //e.g. ["ALPHA_MIKE]
    getTranslation: {} //e.g. {"ALPHA_MIKE": "ALPHA MIKE"}
    }
},
computed: {
    allkeys() {
        return this.originalKeys.map(key => this.getTranslation[key])
    }
}
```

I'm not sure you need to assign `this.selected = tableHeaders[0]` since the first option will be chosen by default automatically.