# Vue show compopent always if once logic true

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want always show compopent **if logic one time is true**.

I try add and set new var , but get "Unexpected side effect in "canShowAlways" computed property".

How i can do it in vue ?

```
<mycomp v-if="canShowAlways" />

    data: function(){
      return {
        a: 0,
        b: 4,
        c: 1
        d: 2,
        isAlwaysShow: false
      }
    }
    computed: {
        canShowAlways() {
            if(this.isAlwaysShow){
                return true;
            }
            var isLast = this.a && this.b || this.c && this.d;
            if(isLast){
                this.isAlwaysShow = true;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
```

Comment: this looks kinda strange, what is your plan, what do you want to achive

Comment: You shouldn't assign value in computed function. Use a watcher for `canShowAlways`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not edit other data in computed property.

This line `this.isAlwaysShow = true;` is most likely what causes the error that you see in your code.

If you really wanted to stick to the code you have above, then a quick solution would be to call a method that would change the value of `this.isAlwaysShow`.

Otherwise, you would set a `watch` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757107/handling-unexpected-side-effect-in-computed-properties-vuejs).

There is most likely a better way to handle what you are trying to do but more information would need to be provided.