# Why Am I getting error return in computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using `Vuex`, inside `Getter Foo function` I'm returning two values inside array:

`return ["Try Again"]` or `return ["Data result", data]`, in computed, I'm checking the `array length` and returning depending on result

```
  computed:{    
    Foo: function(){
      const getFoo =  this.$store.getters.Foo;
      if(getFoo.length === 1) {
        this.existFoo = false
        return getFoo[0]
      }
      this.existFoo = true
      return getFoo
    }
  }
```

but I'm getting this error, even reading others posts I cannot solve it

> 34:9  error  Unexpected side effect in "Foo" computed property
> vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
> 37:7  error  Unexpected
> side effect in "Foo" computed property
> vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties

Comment: may be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757107/handling-unexpected-side-effect-in-computed-properties-vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a watcher to watch the store value and set your local variables.

```js
computed: {
  getFooFromStore() {
    return this.$store.getters.Foo
  }
}

watch: {
  getFooFromStore: function() {
    this.existFoo = this.getFooFromStore[0] ? false : true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking about that, once I'd need to access `data (){ existFoo }` and through from `computed function` is not possible right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your question. You can access data variables in computed properties, but you can't set them in computed properties if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot access from computed properties, but using watch properties could be set any condictions

Answer (score 2):

You are not permitted to change the state in computeds.
Try using another computed instead of `existFoo`

```
  computed:{        
    Foo(){
      if(this.$store.getters.Foo.length === 1) {
        return this.$store.getters.Foo[0]
      }          
      return this.$store.getters.Foo
    },
    existFoo(){
        return this.$store.getters.Foo.length > 1
    }
  }
```

Now you should remove `existFoo` from `state`