# Scope of locally defined variables in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In this sample:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p 
      v-for="prop in receivedPropsLocal"
      :key="prop.id"
    >
        {{prop}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "PropsReceiver",
  props: {
    receivedProps: {        
      required: true,
      type: Array,      
      default() {
        return [];
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      receivedPropsLocal: Array,
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  watch: {
    receivedProps: {
      deep: true,
      handler(val) {
        let tmp = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, val));
        this.receivedPropsLocal = tmp;
      },
    },
  },
  computed: {
    getReceivedPropsLocal: {
      get() {
        if (!this.receivedPropsLocal) {
          let tmp = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, this.receivedProps));
          this.receivedPropsLocal = tmp;
          return this.receivedPropsLocal;
        }
        return this.receivedPropsLocal;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.receivedPropsLocal = value;
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

what's the scope of `tmp`? Is it handled similarly to other entries in `data()` or not? or it doesn't matter.

Comment: `tmp` is a local variable. It is not an entry in `data()`. It is completely invisible to Vue.

Comment: That makes intuitive sense; there is a "caveat" though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757193/1079483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `tmp`is only accessible from inside the handler function since you used `let` to declare it.

You should declare it directly in the `data` object to use it anywhere in the component.